# Using filter() method in ES6 notation to parse a 1D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

The following snippet in my codebase returns a `map` of an array and I am wondering how can I pass a filter for e.g `status = 2` so that I will only get the filtered output. Should I `filter` the array and then use `map` or just filter the data without mapping.

It could be either pure JS or Lodash method

P.S I am hoping to print the final output inside the `return` statement as mentioned in the snippet.

```js
const data = {
  "edges": [{
      "node": {
        "id": 20,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 20"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 19,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 19"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 18,
        "status": 2,
        "info": "Order info 18"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 17,
        "status": 3,
        "info": "Order info 17"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 16,
        "status": 2,
        "info": "Order info 16"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 15,
        "status": 2,
        "info": "Order info 15"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 14,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 14"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 13,
        "status": 2,
        "info": "Order info 13"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 12,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 12"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 11,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 11"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 10,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 10"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 9,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 9"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 8,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 4"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 7,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 8"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 6,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 7"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 5,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 6"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 4,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 5"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 3,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "info": "Order info 1"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const myFunction = () => {
  return data.edges.map(({
    node: {
      id,
      status,
      info
    }
  }) => {
    return(
      <span>{id}</span>
      <span>{status}</span>
      <span>{info}</span>
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter and map in the same operation (i.e. without iterating over the data twice), you need to use `reduce`:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  return data.edges.reduce((result, {
    node: {
      id,
      status,
      info
    }
  }) => {
    if (status === 2) {
      return result.concat(<div><span>{id}</span><span>{status}</span><span>{info}</span></div>);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
};
```

Note that `<span>{id}</span><span>{status}</span><span>{info}</span>`, per your comment, is not valid JSX (what would it transpile to?). In order to make it valid I've wrapped it in a `<div>` above. Alternatively, you could pass three arguments to `concat`, but then you'll have to make sure each

```
result.concat(<span>{id}</span>, <span>{status}</span>, <span>{info}</span>);
```

Note also that if you're using React, [elements in an array usually need a `key`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const data = {
  "edges": [
    { "node": { "id": 20, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 20" } },
    { "node": { "id": 19, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 19" } },
    { "node": { "id": 18, "status": 2, "info": "Order info 18" } },
    { "node": { "id": 17, "status": 3, "info": "Order info 17" } },
    { "node": { "id": 16, "status": 2, "info": "Order info 16" } },
    { "node": { "id": 15, "status": 2, "info": "Order info 15" } },
    { "node": { "id": 14, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 14" } },
    { "node": { "id": 13, "status": 2, "info": "Order info 13" } },
    { "node": { "id": 12, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 12" } },
    { "node": { "id": 11, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 11" } },
    { "node": { "id": 10, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 10" } },
    { "node": { "id": 9, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 9" } },
    { "node": { "id": 8, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 4" } },
    { "node": { "id": 7, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 8" } },
    { "node": { "id": 6, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 7" } },
    { "node": { "id": 5, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 6" } },
    { "node": { "id": 4, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 5" } },
    { "node": { "id": 3, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 3" } },
    { "node": { "id": 2, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 2" } },
    { "node": { "id": 1, "status": 1, "info": "Order info 1" } }
  ]
}

const myFunction = () => data.edges.reduce(
  (result, { node: { id, status, info } }) => {
    if (status === 2) {
      return result.concat(<div><span>{id}</span><span>{status}</span><span>{info}</span></div>);
    }
    return result;
  }, []
);

console.log(myFunction());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Having a bit of trouble in the line `return status === 2 ? result.concat(status) : result;` How can I render html tags and print the values `<span>{id}</span><span>{status}</span><span>{info}</span>`

Comment: @zaq I'll edit my answer to show how to do that, but you should also edit your question to indicate that that's the result you want.

Comment: I will update my question with clear information. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You could just filter the array and map the wanted string with a template literal.

```js
var data = { edges: [{ node: { id: 20, status: 1, info: "Order info 20" } }, { node: { id: 19, status: 1, info: "Order info 19" } }, { node: { id: 18, status: 2, info: "Order info 18" } }, { node: { id: 17, status: 3, info: "Order info 17" } }, { node: { id: 16, status: 2, info: "Order info 16" } }, { node: { id: 15, status: 2, info: "Order info 15" } }, { node: { id: 14, status: 1, info: "Order info 14" } }, { node: { id: 13, status: 2, info: "Order info 13" } }, { node: { id: 12, status: 1, info: "Order info 12" } }, { node: { id: 11, status: 1, info: "Order info 11" } }, { node: { id: 10, status: 1, info: "Order info 10" } }, { node: { id: 9, status: 1, info: "Order info 9" } }, { node: { id: 8, status: 1, info: "Order info 4" } }, { node: { id: 7, status: 1, info: "Order info 8" } }, { node: { id: 6, status: 1, info: "Order info 7" } }, { node: { id: 5, status: 1, info: "Order info 6" } }, { node: { id: 4, status: 1, info: "Order info 5" } }, { node: { id: 3, status: 1, info: "Order info 3" } }, { node: { id: 2, status: 1, info: "Order info 2" } }, { node: { id: 1, status: 1, info: "Order info 1" } }] },
    myFunction = _ => data.edges.
        filter(a => a.node.status === 2).
        map(({ node: { id, status, info } }) => `<div><span>${id}</span> <span>${status}</span> <span>${info}</span></div>`);

console.log(myFunction());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How about if I would like to keep the destructuring and print out the data. Something like `return data.edges.filter(({ node: { id, status, info } }) => { return ( <div> <span>{id}</span> <span>{status}</span> <span>{info}</span> </div> ); });` Where should I exactly pass `status === 2`. Probably, the same way I explained in my original question.

Comment: for this, you need two pass, one for fuiltering and then mapping, because filter does not alter the items and map does return something for every element.

Comment: I think I should have explained it in my question a bit better. I would like to filter and then map to represent the given array

Comment: Hei!  :-O  Verdammtes Mädchen, hör auf, uns schlecht erscheinen zu lassen.

Answer (score 0):

```
twoEdges = edges.filter((thingy) => { return (thingy.node.status === 2);});
```

or
`twoEdges = edges.filter((thingy) => thingy.node.status === 2 );` ... or something like that